# Ajuda para cálculos de Dilatação Linear em Python

Tags: python, matemática

Olá. Esta é minha primeira postagem no StackOverflow então mil perdões se eu vier a cometer algum erro.

Pessoal, podem me ajudar? Estou tentando desenvolver um código em Python que consiga calcular a Dilatação Linear de algum material informado via função.
Mas estou com um problema na hora de setar o alpha na equação. Em física, um exemplo de alpha para cálculos de dilatação linear é (10 * 1,2^-5)°C ^-1. Mas se eu colocar este cálculo em uma variável python, na hora de tentar printar, ele exibe isto como um cálculo e não como um valor.

Um exemplo:

Dilatação linear de uma placa de ferro cuja o (delta)T (temperatura final menos a temperatura inicial) será 30m, a tamanho da placa será 100m e o alpha será (10*1,2^-5)°C ^-1

Delta L = 100 x (10*1,2^-5) x 30
Delta L = 3600^-5m °C ^-1
(Não estou continuando para evitar alguma dízima)

Este é o resultado da equação 3600^-5 m °C ^-1

Se eu quisesse reproduzir este mesmo cálculo em python e fazer que o resultado impresso seja o mesmo, como eu deveria fazer?

Comment: Bem vindo, Mostre-nos como tentou fazer em Python...

Comment: eu nem tentei pois já sabia que o interpretador ia considerar (10*1,2^-5)°C ^-1 como um cálculo, quero saber como posso fazer este código

Comment: hummm qual a versão Python está usando ?

Comment: Isso está confuso. Ambos `*` e `x` no seu código representam multiplicação? `10*1,2^-5` pode ser escrito como `1.2 * (10 ** -5)`, isso ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Não sei qual versão Python está usando, mas para a versão Python3.X eu faria simplesmente assim:

```
Placa=100
Temperatura=30
L=Placa*(10*1.2) * Temperatura / 10    
print(int(L),'^-5 m °C ^-1',sep='')
```

Resultado:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2018, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
3600^-5 m °C ^-1
```

Outra maneira conforme meu comentário:

```
alpha='10*1.2^-5'
Placa=100
Temperatura=30
[calc, string ]=alpha.split('^')
L=Placa*(eval(calc)) * Temperatura / 10    
print(int(L),'^',string,' m °C ^-1',sep='')
```

Resultado:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2018, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
3600^-5 m °C ^-1
```

Comment: cara o problema tá ai. O alpha das equações é diferente de material para material. eu queria fazer uma função aonde eu passava os valores e ele exibia o cálculo mas o python (uso o 3.6) não entende o 10x1,2^-5 como uma informação e sim como um cálculo

Comment: ué o código é praticamente o mesmo, crie mais duas variáveis uma chamada alpha=10*1.2 e outra variável do tipo string recebendo "^-5" depois só concatenar como eu fiz no print... se quiser ser mais esperto ainda poderia colocar tudo em uma variável só e depois dar um split ... veja a reposta novamente

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudarem. Consegui fazer o código baseado no que o ederwander fez. Coloquei o código numa função e coloquei um if para evitar erros de substituição de '.' por ','.